# How can I make text appear on scrolling like the following website

Tags: text, scroll, show, effect

Can someone help me with the following problem. I want to make text appear and flow to the right at the same time like this website: https://www.wokine.com/en/ . How should my code look like?

Answer (score 0):

There are a series of solutions to that and writing about them all in detail would take forever, I'm just going to share a few of my favourite libraries and a few resources on them.

[AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) is in my opinion the nicest library doing what you want to do. It's on [Github](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos).

[WOW.js](https://www.delac.io/wow/) is another library that does what you are looking for, but it has some strange licensing.

With a queck search I could also find [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/), I have no experience with that one.

Hope it helps get you started!